# Prove that there are integral solutions to $\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\frac{1}{x_3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}=1$ if $n \ge 6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

We need to prove that the equation
$$\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\frac{1}{x_3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}=1$$ has integral solutions for all $n\ge 6$

The best i could think of was inverses of atleast $6$ perfect squares add up to $1$

What kind of approach should we have to solve these kinds of problems? I find one of these problems that i can't solve, what should i try then?
All **Hints** are welcome and full length solutions discouraged

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint :** Induction on $n$.

Find explicit solutions for $n=6$, $n=7$ and $n=8$. Then, considering $\lbrace x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, 2x_n, 2x_n, 2x_n, 2x_n \rbrace$, show that if you have a solution for $n$, you have a solution for $n+3$.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Perhaps it's even easier to find for $n=4, n=5$ and $n=6$. Which makes me wonder if $n=3$ is the only one that's impossible.

Comment: I think there is no solution for $n=5$ (as well as $n=2$ !).

Comment: What about the other part regarding getting struck?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe in my mind I could write 1 as 0.25+0.25+0.25+0.16+0.09 but couldn't find a way to break it into 3 squares.

Comment: @cgss $0.16$ and $0.09$ are not inverses of squares !

Comment: Oh yes you are right. My bad.